# Determining if the current span is an attribute deleration using Roslyn APIs

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm building a visual studio extension for coloring various language constructs using Roslyn APIs, I want to change the color of attribute declarations, like Asp.Net MVC `[Require]` attribute for example. I have access to `SyntaxNode` and `ISymbol`, my current check to find out if the current node is an attribute declaration is:

```
public static bool IsCSharpAttributeSyntaxKind(this SyntaxNode node)
{
        return node.Kind() == SyntaxKind.Attribute;
}
```

And use it like:

```
if (node.IsCSharpAttributeSyntaxKind())
  {
     classificationTypeDictionary.TryGetValue(ColorCoderClassificationName.Attribute, out IClassificationType classificationValue);

     return new TagSpan<IClassificationTag>(new SnapshotSpan(snapshot, span.TextSpan.Start, span.TextSpan.Length), new ClassificationTag(classificationValue));
   }
```

I get the Roslyn info by:

```
public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<IClassificationTag>> GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        if (spans.Count == 0)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ITagSpan<IClassificationTag>>();
        }

        var cacheStatus = _colorCoderTaggerServices.ManageCache(ref _cache, spans, _buffer);

        if (cacheStatus == CacheState.NotResolved)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ITagSpan<IClassificationTag>>();
        }

        return _colorCoderTaggerServices.GetClassificationTags(_cache, spans, classificationTypeDictionary);
    }
```

Also the method for retrieving the identifiers:

```
internal IEnumerable<ClassifiedSpan> GetIdentifiersInSpans(Workspace workspace, SemanticModel model, NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
 {
    var comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

    var classifiedSpans = spans.SelectMany(span =>
    {
       var textSpan = TextSpan.FromBounds(span.Start, span.End);
        return Classifier.GetClassifiedSpans(model, textSpan, workspace);
    });

    return classifiedSpans.Where(c => comparer.Compare(c.ClassificationType, "identifier") == 0);
}
```

I don't know if the attribute declaration is part of the identifiers that I return form `GetIdentifiersInSpans`, but I did it without the `Where` with no success.

And for my caching mechanism I use:

```
public class ProviderCache
{
    public Workspace Workspace { get; private set; }
    public Document Document { get; private set; }
    public SemanticModel SemanticModel { get; private set; }
    public SyntaxNode SyntaxRoot { get; private set; }
    public ITextSnapshot Snapshot { get; private set; }

    public static async Task<ProviderCache> Resolve(ITextBuffer buffer, ITextSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        var workspace = buffer.GetWorkspace();
        var document = snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
        if (document == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return new ProviderCache
        {
            Workspace = workspace,
            Document = document,
            SemanticModel = semanticModel,
            SyntaxRoot = syntaxRoot,
            Snapshot = snapshot
        };
    }
}
```

I've tried various other things but none of them worked, I believe I miss something else here. I understand that my question is not good enough, I'm sorry for that, that's because I lack the terminology to ask a good question, and visual studio's extensibility frameworks are usually under-documented, if you need any more detail please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the question?

Comment: @svick You're right, the question was not clear, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you are getting the roslyn info in your extension, but because you mention `SyntaxNode` `Workspace` and `SemanticModel` in your code samples, I assume you can get the current `Document`. The approach I would take is to get the root node for the document you are attempting to classify.  A good starting place would be somthing like the code below and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Todo_Classification) VSSDK sample.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<ClassificationSpan>> ClassifyAttributes(Document currentDocument, CancellationToken token)
{
    // Get all attribute nodes in the current document
    var rootNode = await currentDocument.GetSyntaxRootAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var attributesInDocument = from descendantNode in rootNode.DescendantNodesAndSelf()
                               where descendantNode.IsKind(SyntaxKind.Attribute)
                               select (AttributeSyntax)descendantNode;

    // Check to see if the attribute binds to a type (I assume you do not want to classify attributes with errors)
    var model = await currentDocument.GetSemanticModelAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var attributeSpans = from attributeNode in attributesInDocument
                         let typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(attributeNode, token)
                         where typeInfo.Type.Kind != SymbolKind.ErrorType
                         select new ClassificationSpan(attributeNode.Span, _classificationType);

    // returns a set of ClassifiedSpans that your extensions classifer will colorize
    return attributeSpans;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry for not explaining adequately what I'm after, I've added some more info, what I want is to determine if the current node is attribute declaration, like customs attributes, I have no problem in mechanism used to do it, also the check `rootNode.DescendantNodesAndSelf() where descendantNode.IsKind(SyntaxKind.Attribute)` didn't solve the problem.